# Java version 1.5 or 1.7?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using jdk1.7 with netbeans or at least that is what is shown when I click on tools=>platforms.

However, when I try something like this, for instance:

```
switch (xyz)
```

where `xyz` is a `String`, then I get an error telling me that this is not allowed with Java 5.

How can this be? Is there a way to change this without uninstalling everything?

Comment: Which JRE are you using?

Comment: Also check Tools > Java Platforms.

Comment: did that before I posted, did not work so I posted. But the answer below solved my problem, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project and select "sources" from left pane ---> Change Source/BinaryFormat drop down to Java7.

Comment: I am accepting in 5 Minutes. did the trick, though the exact way was right click=>config=>sourches

Comment: I think Netbean version may be different here.

Comment: Mine is 7.0.1, things might have changed.